# Why does my page with bootstrap 4 look like this in medium resolutions?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In my simple page with Bootstrap 4, when the screen size is medium look like with this blank space en the right.

[image: blank space in the right]

[The page](https://melting-chapter.000webhostapp.com/)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not enough information.  Please include the code in question and a description of the problem see [How do i ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @bhmahler advice is good _ Check out the FAQ links in their comment. No-one can help if we don't have the code to work with _ Think about the effort SO contributors will put into answering for a moment, then try and put the same amount of effort into writing / editing your question

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is the class "card-deck", it is pushing the all page to the right a little bit. Just add the following style inline the html and the problem will be solved:

```
style="margin-right:15px;"
```

The result will be this one:

```
<div class="card-deck" style="margin-right:15px;">
```

Comment: his css already contains a "margin-right: -15px;", so just removing this option will make the page fit right..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ As well as being helpful now, this site is focused on creating useful questions and answers for all visitors in the future _ In its current state this question is not good and will likely be closed. Please read this FAQ on answering SO questions, and specifically the section on 'Answering well-asked questions' >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the property `margin-right: -15px;` of the class `card-deck`, that is applied from the media query: `@media (min-width: 576px)`. Setting the margin right to 0 should fix this.

```
@media (min-width: 576px)
.card-deck { 
margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it inside class="container" or class="container-fluid"

Answer (score -2):

It is unclear what is the design requirement for the *card-deck* section, but I can suggest two approaches:

1. Remove the *margin-left* and *margin-right* properties. Then the borders of the cards will not "touch" the ends of the screen, which resembles the typical Bootstrap layout.
2. Just as the point above - remove the side margins of the *card-deck* and also set to 0 the left margin of the first card and the right margin of the last card. This will keep your current design of the cards in the section, that "touch" the ends of the screen, if this is what you are targeting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ As well as being helpful now, this site is focused on creating useful questions and answers for all visitors in the future _ In its current state this question is not good and will likely be closed. Please read this FAQ on answering SO questions, and specifically the section on 'Answering well-asked questions' >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer